# How to access DOM after extension installation in Safari

Tags: javascript, dom, safari, safari-extension

Is it possible, to access DOM after completing installation of the Safari extension?
I'm interested in accessing into HTML of the page from which this extension is being installed.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by injecting JS scripts. The injected scripts have access to the DOM of the webpages they are injected into. Injected scripts have the same access privileges as scripts executed from the webpage’s host.

You can find more information [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/InjectingScripts/InjectingScripts.html).

**Calling a Function from an Injected Script**

1. List item
2. Create an extension folder using Extension Builder. Copy the
3. listings into a text editor and save as Injected.js and Global.html.
4. Drag Injected.js and Global.html into your extension folder. Click
5. Extension Global Page in Extension Builder and choose Global.html.
6. Click New Script in End Scripts and choose Injected.js. Set the
7. Extension Website Access level to All. Click Install.

**Code** Injected.js

```
var initialVal=1;
var calculatedVal=0 ;

function doBigCalc(theData) {
    safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("calcThis",theData);
}

function getAnswer(theMessageEvent) {
    if (theMessageEvent.name === "theAnswer") {
        calculatedVal=theMessageEvent.message;
        console.log(calculatedVal);
    }
}
safari.self.addEventListener("message", getAnswer, false);

doBigCalc(initialVal);
```

**Code** Global.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>global HTML page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function bigCalc(startVal, event) {
    // imagine hundreds of lines of code here...
    var endVal = startVal + 2;
    // return to sender
    event.target.page.dispatchMessage("theAnswer", endVal);
}

function respondToMessage(theMessageEvent) {
    if(theMessageEvent.name === "calcThis") {
        var startVal=theMessageEvent.message;
        bigCalc(startVal, theMessageEvent);
    }
}

    safari.application.addEventListener("message",respondToMessage,false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So why my extension returns me null when I try to get an element by document.getElementById ?

Here you can find my extension: http://proto.hiryuu.eu/safari.html

Comment: First of all I want to thank you for reply Gurpreet Singh.
I'm sorry but I think we do not understand each other.
I want to start working my extension RIGHT AFTER its installation.
So client clicks "install" and right after that the extension is starting to work. 
Just like restartless/bootstarpped extensions in Firefox.

I don't want to start my extension after opening new tab or after reload a page.
If it isn't possible tell me how to reload page with $_POST data.

Comment: This is a feature request we've been beating the drum about for years. It doesn't look like the Safari team has interest in it. We now have a prompt in our extension that says something like, "This page was loaded before the extension was installed. Please reload the page."

Comment: @jxpx777 - How do you detect the condition that the page was loaded before the extension was installed?